# C# parallel.Do on assigning elements of DataTable

Tags: datatable

**i am trying to fill each half of the datatable in parallel,but it didnt work, here is how i made the call:**

```
Parallel.Do(
                () => fillParallel(0, t.Rows.Count / 2, values, t),
                () => fillParallel(t.Rows.Count / 2, t.Rows.Count, values, t));
```

**and here is the function:**

```
void fillParallel(int l,int h,string[]v,DataTable t)
        {
            for (int rowIndex = l; rowIndex < h; rowIndex++)
                for (int columnIndex = 0; columnIndex <t.Rows.Count; columnIndex++)
                   t.Rows[rowIndex][columnIndex] = v[(rowIndex * t.Rows.Count) + columnIndex];
        }
```

**when i made the calls sequentially it worked out, but when i tried to make it in parallel i got an (index out of range) error, why is that?**

Answer (score 1):

DataTables are not threadsafe.

You can't do that.